# How to complete a TexLive installation in mainland China?

Tags: texlive, installing

Ubuntu 22.04. I'm living in Guangzhou, China. I do have a VPN so The Firewall is not an insurmountable obstacle.

Per https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html, I started the Internet-based installation.

It estimated 14 hours to complete.

So then I started looking into mirroring the repository, and encountered even more problems.

The nearest mirror is in Shenzhen.

```
rsync -a --delete rsync://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/ ./mirror
```

SImply waits... and waits... and waits... and waits...

"So, a CTAN volunteer wrote a ctan-mirrors script to ping listed mirrors so you can determine the closest one to you." -- tried this.

```
perl ./ctan-mirrors -p rsync
```

It waits... and waits... and waits... and waits...

```
wget --mirror --no-parent ftp://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/ ./mirror
```

Connection times out (this is about 80 km away, it shouldn't be that bad, unless the mirror is down or they broke the external access permissions or whatever).

So I'm looking for recommendations. I guess if all else fails, I could just leave the computer on overnight running the Internet install script.

But I would seriously hope that there's a better way...? Is there a better way?

Comment: Is it possible to install using apt? I am not sure about the speed though. Another approach is to download the ISO image: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html

Comment: Downloading the ISO image (4 GB) and running the install locally is much faster than the over-the-net install (which does file-by-file, from what I can see).

Comment: Ah OK, thanks, I'll try the ISO.

Comment: Solved by installing from ISO.